# SSIS Fuzzy Lookup match only once to source

Tags: ssis, fuzzy-logic

I'm having a bit of trouble with SSIS Fuzzy Lookup. What I would like to do is have two sets of unique data. For set 1 I want to make a fuzzy lookup on set 2, once the strongest match has been found the item in set 2 is no longer considered for further matching.

[image]

I've attached an image to help describe what I'd like to do. As you can see the Fuzzy Lookup found a strong match for "The Westin Seattle" of 71% and a slightly weaker match of 65%. What I'd like to achieve is for the strongest match to return and for all other lookups only consider records that have not already been matched. So in this example "Seattle Westin Hotel" in the lookup data is matched to "The Westin Seattle" and no longer available in the lookup process. Therefore it will not be a candidate for matching when "Sherton Seattle Hotel" is the lookup key.